# p_txn_ln subsequent lines of tax not allowed

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Getting this error when sending Invoice to QuickBooks Premier 2013 with IPP. What does this error mean?

We are setting a Sales Tax Item as a line item in the invoice.

Comment: Please post your request/response XML